# C++, container vector of pointers, overloading operator<<

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to take out to the console window my vector of pointers but still doesn't work. I can fill the vector but when I try to cout<< my object noting comes out on the console window.

This is header file with declarations of the private class members and functions:

```
#pragma once
#include"CDealer.h"
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iterator>
    class CShop
    {
    public:
        CShop();
        ~CShop();
        CShop(const string &fname);
        friend ostream &operator << (ostream &toStream, const CShop &S);
        friend istream &operator >> (istream &fromStream, CShop &S);

    private:
        string m_strNameShop;
        string m_strCity;
        vector<CDealer*> Dealers;

    };
```

This is my constructor with file from where I bring the data

```
#include "CShop.h"

CShop::CShop(){}
CShop::~CShop(){}

        CShop::CShop(const string &fname)
    {
        fstream File(fname, ios::in);
        if (File.is_open())
        {
            CDealer c;
            File >> m_strNameShop;
            File >> m_strCity;

            while (File.is_open())
            {
                File >> c;
                Dealers.push_back(new CDealer(c));
            }
            File.close();   
        }
        else
            throw "ERROR! ";
    }
```

and this is overloading operator<<:

```
    ostream &operator << (ostream &toStream, const CShop &S)
{
    return toStream << "Name Shop: " << S.m_strNameShop << " City: " << S.m_strCity;

    vector<CDealer *>::const_iterator it = S.Dealers.begin();
    while (it != S.Dealers.end())
    {
        toStream << "Dealer " << *it++;
    }

}
```

So in the end my main

```
#include"CShop.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    CShop SS1("data.txt");
        cout << SS1;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
```

Please help Me :)

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: When I copy-and-paste this code, it does not compile.  Appears to be missing `#include` and other parts.  If those parts are not relevant, trim them out of your code that is supposed to reproduce the problem.  Make sure you have all the warnings enabled in your compiler.

Comment: When I put breakpoint on the  Dealers.push_back(new CDealer(c)); I can see that vector is filled but in the end on the console I can see only m_strNameShop and m_strCity, when I put breakpoint on the  while (it != S.Dealers.end())
    {
        toStream << "Dealer " << *it++;
    }
does not enter it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a premature `return` in the function.

```
 return toStream << "Name Shop: " << S.m_strNameShop << " City: " << S.m_strCity;
 //^^^
```

Remove it.

```
toStream << "Name Shop: " << S.m_strNameShop << " City: " << S.m_strCity;
```

Add  a `return` before the end of the function.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& toStream, const CShop &S)
{
   toStream << "Name Shop: " << S.m_strNameShop << " City: " << S.m_strCity;

   vector<CDealer *>::const_iterator it = S.Dealers.begin();
   while (it != S.Dealers.end())
   {
      toStream << "Dealer " << *it++;
   }

   return toStream;
}
```

---

Suggestions for further improvement.

The line

```
      toStream << "Dealer " << *it++;
```

will print only the pointer values. If you want to print the details of the object the pointers point to, change it to:

```
      Dealer* dealerPtr = *it++;
      toStream << "Dealer " << *dealerPtr;
```

The following block is not right. `File.is_open()` will be always `true` in this block.

```
 while (File.is_open())
 {
    File >> c;
    Dealers.push_back(new CDealer(c));
 }
```

Change it to:

```
 while (File >> c)
 {
    Dealers.push_back(new CDealer(c));
 }
```

Comment: @Kristiyan, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.